# Long table scroll, but prevent window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table whith many `div`s above it:

```
<div></div>...<div></div>
<div id="tablecontent">
<table>...</table>

</div>
```

I want my table scroll only in screen (the bottom of table is in the bottom of windows). So I need to set height and `scroll=auto` for `#tablecontent`.
To set heigth I calculate it as:

```
var pos=$("#tablecontent").position().top;
var heigth=$( window ).height()-pos;
$("#tablecontent").css("height",heigth+'px');
```

But this is not working correctly. It is larger  than I need. Can you help me calculating the right value.

Comment: The extra height most likely comes from margins or paddings surrounding the elements' parent. Is it only a bottom padding that's sticking out of your window?

Answer (score 1):

On the `div` in your CSS you'll want to set `overflow: scroll`, that with the fixed height should create a scroll bar on your `div` when the contents are larger than the container.